# Scala List Regex match in Map and return key

Tags: scala

I want to match a string with list of regex within a `Map[String, List[Regex]]` and return the `key[String]` as String in case there is a match.

e.g:

```
 //Map[String, List[Regex]]

 Map(m3 -> List(([^ ]*)(rule3)([^ ]*)), m1 -> List(([^ ]*)(rule1)([^ ]*)), m4 -> List(([^ ]*)(rule5)([^ ]*)), m2 -> List(([^ ]*)(rule2)([^ ]*)))
```

if the string is `"***rule3****"` it should return me  the key `"m3"`, similarly if the string is `"****rule5****"` it should return key  `"m4"`.

How do i implement this?

something that i tried which is not working

```
rulesMap.mapValues (y => y.par.foreach (x => x.findFirstMatchIn("description"))).keys.toString()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Scala 2.13.x

```scala
rulesMap
  .filter({ case (_, regexList) => regexList.exists(regex => regex.matches("yourString")) })
  .keys
```

For Scala 2.12.x

```scala
rulesMap
  .filter({ case (_, regexList) => regexList.exists(regex => regex.findFirstIn("yourString").isDefined) })
  .keys
```

Comment: Error: value matches is not a member of scala.util.matching.Regex

Comment: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/matching/Regex.html#matches(source:CharSequence):Boolean

Comment: looks like you are using scala-2.12.x

Answer (score 0):

`collect` is the best way of both filtering and mapping a collection because it only does a single pass over the data.

```
def findKeys(s: String) =
  rulesMap.collect {
    case (key, exps) if exps.exists(_.findFirstIn(s).nonEmpty) => key
  }
```